# Соединить две (или более) текстуры в одну

Tags: c++, opengl

Долгое время воевал один с этой задачей, но больше сил нет.
Простая задача - объединить две (или более) картинки в одну, чтобы наложить на эту общую шейдер.

*Вообще всё началось с того, что свет накладывается отдельной картинкой, но шейдеры почему-то не учитывают положение на экране и применяют эффект к центру.*

На чём остановился сейчас:

Функция для создания фреймбуффера

```
void glGenTextureFromFramebuffer(GLuint *t, GLuint *f, GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, f);
    glGenTextures(1, t);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, *f);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *t);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, *t, 0);

    GLuint depthbuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, w, h);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        warning("Framebuffer status", "wtf");// status);
}
```

Отрисовка с помощью

```
void test_draw2(GLuint* texture, int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); {
        glTexCoord2d(0, 0); glVertex3f(x, y, 0);
        glTexCoord2d(1, 0); glVertex3f(x + w, y, 0);
        glTexCoord2d(1, 1); glVertex3f(x + w, y + h, 0);
        glTexCoord2d(0, 1); glVertex3f(x, y + h, 0);
    } glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Использование:

```
// obj1 и obj2 без буффера рендерятся как надо.
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);
test_draw2(&obj1, 1920 / 2.f, 1080 / 2.f, width, height);
test_draw2(&obj2, 1920 / 2.f, 1080 / 2.f, width, height);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
test_draw2(&_texture, 1920 / 2.f, 1080 / 2.f, width, height);
```

Результат: чёрный квадрат.

Изменено: добавил код шейдера, хоть и не очень понимаю, как он поможет сложить текстуры в одну. Его суть - наложить эффект color dodge, чтобы симулировать свет в 2д игре со слоями. С радостью бы использовал обычный SDL2, но тот не поддерживает шейдеры.

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D background;

float blendColorDodge(float base, float blend) {
    return (blend==1.0)?blend:min(base/(1.0-blend),1.0);
}

vec3 blendColorDodge(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {
    return vec3(blendColorDodge(base.r,blend.r),blendColorDodge(base.g,blend.g),blendColorDodge(base.b,blend.b));
}

vec3 blendColorDodge(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {
    return (blendColorDodge(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));
}

void main (void)
{
    vec4 c = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 blend = texture2D(background, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec3 f = blendColorDodge(c.rgb, blend.rgb);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(f.r, f.g, f.b, c.a );
}
```

Comment: Ну вот вы пишите "наложить шейдер", а в приведенном коде видно только использование фиксированного конвеера через вызов устаревших `glBegin` `glEnd`

Comment: Но шейдер работает, поэтому и не указываю всё, что с ним связано. Не работает приведённый код, а именно - чёрный экран вместо текстуры, созданной из двух других.
p.s. добавил код шейдера

Comment: Как же он работает, если текстура не отрисовывается?

Comment: Да так он работает, что если убрать буферизацию, что всё отлично. Вопрос в том, как соединить две (или двадцать две) текстуры в одну текстуру, и уже на этом моменте не работает. Как можно оценивать работоспособность шейдера, если его не на что применять?

Comment: Как-то вы непонятно изъясняетесь. У вас render to texture не работает? Приведенный шейдер это для render to texture? В нем `texture` и `background` действительно содержат нужные текстуры? По идее у вас же должно быть 4 шейдера. Может вы вообще что-то другое делаете? Как используется glGenTextureFromFramebuffer?

Comment: У меня не получается создать текстуру из нескольких других. Грубо говоря, я загружаю картинки: фон, персонаж, ящики, свет от лампы. Затем я хочу соединить фон, персонажа (в нужной позиции) и ящики в одну текстуру, назовём её "new_texture". А уже после этого наложить текстуру "свет от лампы" на "new_texture" с использованием шейдера. Вот "new_texture" получается чёрный квадрат, поэтому до шейдера я ещё не дошёл.

Comment: Мне кажется, что при настройке текстуры new_texture у вас пропущен вызов `glDrawBuffers`, задающий вывод изображения в приаттаченную текстуру.

Comment: @VTT Емнип, `glDrawBuffers` нужен, если шейдер рисует в несколько текстур одновременно. А для одной - правильные настройки стоят по умолчанию, и его можно не использовать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat framebuffer это правильный путь для того, чтобы отрендерить 2 текстуры в одну? Я не понимаю, как соединить две текстуры в одну, уже все страницы гугла фиолетовые от просмотров - всюду ребята 3д превращают в картинку, а мне просто соединить 2 картинки, почему так сложно-то